How do I distribute n objects in m boxes so that it is always spaced out from each other evenly?
I have 12 indices in an array to be filled with 1-11 objects. It should be done in a way such that the objects are atleast slightly evenly spaced from each other.
step = num_boxes // num_objects
indices = [i * step for i in range(num_objects)]

So far I have tried the above method. For example, for 3 objects the indices will be [0, 4, 8]. This way the last 4 boxes are empty. Which is not desired. Ideally the first and the last box (or the last but one box) should be filled and the remaining should be evenly spaced between.
Edit: So the desired indices it should take for objects from 1 to 10 can be for example as image below. I am looking for symmetry from the center.


You could use np.linspace() to spread the indices evenly, after adding the first and last indices as you wish. But your question needs some clarification, it is hard to understand what you really want. Please give some examples (input and what it should output) as well as the values of your variables in the given example

I am not sure if that is what you want, but you can try this:
indices = np.round(np.linspace(0, num_boxes - 1, num_objects)).astype(int)

This would result in an arrangement of boxes like this for the case you mentioned:
[ 0  6 11]


For N objects you have N-1 spaces, last number should be at num_boxes-1
stepf = (num_boxes-1) / (num_objects-1)
indices = [int(i * stepf) for i in range(num_objects)]

To be always sure you end on the last index use
indices = [int(i / (num_objects-1) * (num_boxes-1)) for i in range(num_objects)]

i / (num_objects-1) is 1.0 exact for last element, no rounding errors

You could write a function that places the first and last indices  and then recurses to place the remaining indexes in the inside space which you can compute using an integer division.  The remainder of the division provides you with the extra space to spread progressively between positions:
def spread(size,count,first=0):
    if count<2: return [first+size//2]*count
    step,extra = divmod(size-1,count-1)
    inside     = size - 2*step - min(extra,2)
    return [first]+spread(inside,count-2,first+step+(extra>0))+[first+size-1]

    

output:
for c in range(1,13):
    print(c,spread(12,c))

1 [6]
2 [0, 11]
3 [0, 6, 11]
4 [0, 4, 7, 11]
5 [0, 3, 6, 8, 11]
6 [0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
7 [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11]
8 [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11]
9 [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
10 [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
11 [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
12 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

This will spread extra space from the outside-in (more or less centring the cluster of closer items) but you could use a different scheme if you want to have them placed differently.
For example, using a cumulative offset where you add one for the first items up to the extra space, which will increase spacing only on the left side of the result:
def spread(size,count):
    if count<2: return [size//2]*count
    step,extra = divmod(size-1,count-1)
    indices  =  [0]
    indices  += (indices[-1]+step+(i<extra) for i in range(count-1))
    return indices

output:
1 [6]
2 [0, 11]
3 [0, 6, 11]
4 [0, 4, 8, 11]
5 [0, 3, 6, 9, 11]
6 [0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
7 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11]
8 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]
9 [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
10 [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
11 [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
12 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

You could even spread the extra space randomly:
    from random import sample
    def spread(size,count):
        if count<2: return [size//2]*count
        step,extra = divmod(size-1,count-1 or 1)
        offsets   = [step]*(count-1-extra) + [step+1]*extra
        indices   = [0]
        indices  += (indices[-1]+s for s in sample(offsets,count-1))
        return indices

[Edit] Symetric spread from center.
The distribution of extra space can be done in many different ways.  To get a pretty good symmetrical distribution on the left and right side, you could use the function recursively:
def spread(size,count):
    if count<2: return [size//2]*count
    step,extra = divmod(size-1,count-1)
    chunks = [step]*(count-1)
    for i in spread(count-1,extra):
        chunks[i] += 1
    indices   = [0]
    indices  += (indices[-1]+c for c in chunks)
    return indices

output:
for c in range(1,13):
    A = ["_"]*12
    for i in spread(12,c):
        A[i] = "O"
    A.insert(6,"|")
    print(*A,"",c,spread(12,c))

_ _ _ _ _ _ | O _ _ _ _ _  1 [6]
O _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ O  2 [0, 11]
O _ _ _ _ O | _ _ _ _ _ O  3 [0, 5, 11]
O _ _ _ O _ | _ O _ _ _ O  4 [0, 4, 7, 11]
O _ _ O _ _ | O _ O _ _ O  5 [0, 3, 6, 8, 11]
O _ O _ O _ | _ O _ O _ O  6 [0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 11]
O _ O _ O _ | O O _ O _ O  7 [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11]
O _ O O _ O | O _ O O _ O  8 [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11]
O _ O O O _ | O O O O _ O  9 [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
O _ O O O O | O O O O _ O  10 [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
O O O O O O | _ O O O O O  11 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
O O O O O O | O O O O O O  12 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]


This worked really good initially. But I am looking for symmetry from the middle position. For example for 4 count, [0, 4, 8, 11] was the output. However, it would have bene more desirable to get [0,4,7,11]. For 10 count, [0.1.2.3.4.7,8,9,10,11]
